# how to calculate program performance

Tags: performance

I have a mechanism in place to find the execution time and memory utilization of a program.

I have a list of programs(source code) and I need to find the best performing among them.

```
prog | memory(kb) | time(sec)

1      1200         0.05
2      2200         0.10
3      1970         0.55
```

Is there a formula?

Comment: How do you define "best"? You have two numbers for each and you're trying to reduce them to one; you need to decide how to do that.

Comment: if these are the real numbers from the apps, then first one is the best as it consumes least memory and is the fastest. Otherwise, you need to decide which is the important criteria for you i.e. whether being fastest or being the least consumption of memory or in between. Only then you can deduce the numbers from these data.

Comment: I'm planing to provide more weightage to time. So how about a equation like this `memory+time*20`

Answer (score 1):

I will not answer your question directly since this smells like homework ;P
But I will give you  hint on what to read in-order to solve this 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

if it is java programme then you can use jProfiller